# How to use TensorFlow-experimental framework in my podspec?

Tags: swift, objective-c, tensorflow, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to create a Swift CocoaPods Library, it include an old [Objective-C framework](https://cocoapods.org/pods/TensorFlow-experimental) `'TensorFlow-experimental'`

This is my `.podspec` file setting:

```
  s.dependency 'TensorFlow-experimental'
  #s.static_framework = true
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      'ENABLE_BITCODE' => 'NO',
      "CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER" => "NO",
      "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(inherited) '${PODS_ROOT}/TensorFlow-experimental/Frameworks'",
      "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" => "$(inherited) COCOAPODS=1",
      "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(inherited) '${SRCROOT}/Pods/TensorFlow-experimental/Frameworks/tensorflow_experimental.framework/Headers' '${SRCROOT}/Pods/TensorFlow-experimental/Frameworks/tensorflow_experimental.framework/Headers/third_party/eigen3'",
      "USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "'${SRCROOT}/Pods/TensorFlow-experimental/Frameworks/tensorflow_experimental.framework/Headers' '${SRCROOT}/Pods/TensorFlow-experimental/Frameworks/tensorflow_experimental.framework/Headers/third_party/eigen3'",
      "OTHER_LDFLAGS" => "-force_load '${SRCROOT}/Pods/TensorFlow-experimental/Frameworks/tensorflow_experimental.framework/tensorflow_experimental' '-L ${SRCROOT}/Pods/TensorFlow-experimental/Frameworks/tensorflow_experimental.framework' -lprotobuf_experimental",
      "PODS_BUILD_DIR" => "${BUILD_DIR}",
      "PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR" => "${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)",
      "PODS_ROOT" => "${SRCROOT}",
      "PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT" => "${PODS_ROOT}/TensorFlow-experimental",
      "PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR" => "$(PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/XCFrameworkIntermediates",
      "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" => "org.cocoapods.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}",
      "SKIP_INSTALL" => "YES",
      "USE_RECURSIVE_SCRIPT_INPUTS_IN_SCRIPT_PHASES" => "YES"
      
    }
```

My `-umbrella.h` contains this line
`#import "tensorflow_utils.h"` 
And my `tensorflow_utils.h`:

```
#ifndef TENSORFLOW_CONTRIB_IOS_EXAMPLES_CAMERA_TENSORFLOW_UTILS_H_
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#endif
#define TENSORFLOW_CONTRIB_IOS_EXAMPLES_CAMERA_TENSORFLOW_UTILS_H_

#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/memmapped_file_system.h"
#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"

// Reads a serialized GraphDef protobuf file from the bundle, typically
// created with the freeze_graph script. Populates the session argument with a
// Session object that has the model loaded.
tensorflow::Status LoadModel(NSString* file_name, NSString* file_type,
                             std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>* session);

// Loads a model from a file that has been created using the
// convert_graphdef_memmapped_format tool. This bundles together a GraphDef
// proto together with a file that can be memory-mapped, containing the weight
// parameters for the model. This is useful because it reduces the overall
// memory pressure, since the read-only parameter regions can be easily paged
// out and don't count toward memory limits on iOS.
tensorflow::Status LoadMemoryMappedModel(
                                         NSString* file_name, NSString* file_type,
                                         std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>* session,
                                         std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::MemmappedEnv>* memmapped_env);

// Takes a text file with a single label on each line, and returns a list.
tensorflow::Status LoadLabels(NSString* file_name, NSString* file_type,
                              std::vector<std::string>* label_strings);

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_CONTRIB_iOS_EXAMPLES_CAMERA_TENSORFLOW_UTILS_H_
```

It cause the error: `'tensorflow/core/public/session.h' file not found`

I was searching around some days but still not find the solution. May I missing something in my `.podspec` setting.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe not the whole solution, but you need to uncomment `  #s.static_framework = true` to depend on a static framework binary pod.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do it. But nothing change, still can't import